# Perplexing Abbreviation in Tzafnas Paneach

Tags: rambam, acronyms, acharonim, rogatchover

The [Tzafnas Paneach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Rosen) has a strange abbreviation in his commentary to Rambam, [Sefer Zmanim, Chapter 5, Halacha 5.](https://www.sefaria.org/Tzafnat_Pa%27neach_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Fasts.5.5.1?lang=he)

Here's the Rambam:

> ונהגו כל ישראל בזמנים אלו להתענות בשלשה עשר ג באדר זכר לתענית שהתענו בימי המן שנאמר (אסתר ט׳) דברי הצומות וזעקתם, ואם חל שלשה עשר באדר להיות בשבת מקדימין ומתענין בחמישי שהוא אחד עשר, אבל אחד מארבעה ימי הצומות שחל להיות בשבת דוחין אותו ד לאחר השבת, חל להיות בערב שבת מתענין בערב שבת, ובכל הצומות האלו אין מתריעין ולא מתפללין בהן תפלת נעילה, אבל קורין בתורה שחרית ומנחה בויחל משה, ובכולן אוכלים ושותין בלילה חוץ מתשעה באב.‏

Here's the Tzafnas Paneach

> ונהגו כל ישראל כו׳. עיין **בה״ה** אך באמת אין הפירוש כן רק דקאי אי״ג באדר ובזמן ביהמ״ק אסור להתענות מחמת יום טוריינוס או נקנור כמבואר בתענית דף י״ח ועיין בפה״מ לרבינו בר״ה דס״ל דשל ת״ב אף בבית שני התענו ע״ש וס״ל דגם אז לא היה שלום ובאמת טעם דהוכפלו לא שייך קודם חורבן בית שני וכמ״ש התוס׳ אך באמת לפי הנראה יש בזה שיטה אחרת בענין החורבן ואכמ״ל בזה׃

What is the meaning of "בה״ה"? Its not Halacha 5, because that's the Halacha that he is in. The only commentary on Rambam that has the the initials ה״ה that I could find is הגהות הרמ״ך, and he doesn't have any comments on this Halacha.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It stands for הרב המגיד, meaning the מגיד משנה.